# Ionic SQLite Multi Statements

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am trying to convert T-SQL Query into SQLite in Ionic 3. But I want to be sure if I can write something like this.

```
this.SQLObj.executeSql(`                                        

        CREATE TABLE temp.TempTable (CName TEXT PRIMARY KEY, CValue TEXT);
        INSERT INTO temp.TempTable(CName,CValue) VALUES ('WorkingDays', '2222');
        Select * from temp.TempTable;`, []).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

However, it is not working. I want to know if I can achieve something like this.

Comment: Use three separate executeSql calls, one per statement.

Comment: aren't they asynchronous? and how can I make the final select and get the result ?

Comment: Not normally, no, though I have no idea what whatever language you're using (javascript?) does to the normal sqlite interface. But run one, wait for it to finish, run the next, and so on?